# Problema no retorno json php

Tags: php, jquery, json

Estou com um problema no meu retorno `json` quando tento acessar os dados ele me retorna `object object` segue meu código

`PHP`

```
        $cep = $_POST['cep'];
        $consulta = new Cep();
        $cepCliente = $consulta->getCep($cep);

        $logradouro = $cepCliente->logradouro;
        $complemento = $cepCliente->complemento;
        $bairro = $cepCliente->bairro;
        $localidade = $cepCliente->localidade;
        $uf = $cepCliente->uf;

        $retorno = array("logradouro"=>$logradouro, "complemento"=>$complemento, "bairro"=>$bairro, "localidade"=>$localidade, "uf"=>$uf);
        echo json_encode($retorno);
```

`jQuery`

```
      $.ajax({
        url: 'Controler/consultarCep.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dado,

        success: function(r){
            let result = JSON.parse(r),
                logradouro = result.logradouro;
                complemento = result.complemento;
                bairro = result.bairro;
                localidade = result.localidade,
                uf = result.uf;

                alert(bairro);

        }
      });
```

Comment: No php, a variável `$bairro ` é um objeto ou uma string?

Comment: Utilize console.log no elemento result e no elemento r para saber o que eles são. Pode ajudar

Comment: Tenta usar {type: 'POST', dataType: 'json', data: dado, processData: false,url: 'Controler/consultarCep.php'}. Isso já vai retornar a requisição em formato json, na váriavel r

Answer (score 0):

> **Nestes casos eu uso um *forEach* no javascript**, desta forma e adiciono o campo ***dataType: 'json'***:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Controler/consultarCep.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: dado,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(r){
         r.forEach(resposta);
               }
  });

  function resposta(value, index, ar) {

            logradouro = value.logradouro;
            complemento = value.complemento;
            bairro = value.bairro;
            localidade = value.localidade,
            uf = value.uf;

            alert(bairro);
}
```